# My if and else if are running at the same time

Tags: c

I've got a program measuring distance from a rocket to the moon, so when the distance is >250, only the if runs. However when the else runs and the distance <=250, the if continues to run while the else runs. If anyone can help me fix it I would be very thankful.

```
do
{
if (distance >250)
    {
        time += 1;
        y_pos = initial_y_pos - (vel_y * time)/2;
        x_pos = initial_x_pos + (vel_x * time)/2;
        //Sets the new x and y position when time is flowing so the rocket can move
        GFX_DrawLineTo(x_pos, y_pos, 3);
        GFX_UpdateDisplay();
        distance = sqrt(pow((y_pos-(y+312)),2)+(pow((x_pos-(x+440)),2)));
        mars_dist = sqrt(pow((y_pos-150),2)+pow((x_pos-1150),2));
        //distance calculation from the rocket to the moon. Needed for sphere of influence
        printf("%f\n",distance);
    }

else if (distance <=250)
    {
        y_pos = initial_y_pos - ((vel_y * time) - ((gravity * time)/2));
        x_pos = initial_x_pos + ((vel_x * time) - ((gravity * time)/2));
        GFX_DrawLineTo(x_pos, y_pos, 3);
        GFX_UpdateDisplay();
        distance = sqrt(pow((y_pos-(y+312)),2)+(pow((x_pos-(x+440)),2)));
        mars_dist = sqrt(pow((y_pos-150),2)+pow((x_pos-1150),2));
        //printf("%f\n",distance);
        printf("%f\n", x_pos);
    }


    if (distance <= 50)
    //If the rocket either hits moon or mars, this is responsible for recognising that
    {
        printf("Unlucky! Your rocket crashed into the moon!");
        return 0;
    }

}
//while (distance > 250);
while ((0 <= x_pos && x_pos <= 1280) || (0 <= y_pos && y_pos <= 1024));
```

Comment: inside the `while`, do you want `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: I don't think so as I want the program to stop when the rocket is off the graphics window, so using and wouldn't stop it as soon as the rocket left the window unless it left in one of the corners. I could be wrong though as I'm very new to programming aha. Thanks!

Comment: "the if continues to run while the else runs" - it is unclear what you mean by this.

Comment: So when the distance is less than or equal to 250, the program inside the if statement doesn't stop as expected, however it continues to print the distance and draw new lines.

Comment: I think @SouravGhosh is right here. The way you have it now, the loop continues to run until you go out of bounds on _both_  directions (up/down, left/right).

Comment: The `while` should use `&&`, not `||`. With `||`, it continues if either `x_pos` is in range or `y_pos` is in range. However, a point is inside a rectangle only if both its x coordinate is in range and its y coordinate in range.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. I'll change this to see what happens.

Comment: The question does not explain why OP believes both the `if` and the `else if` execute in the same iteration. I suggest putting `puts("Inside the if.");` inside the `if`, `puts("Inside the else if.");` inside the `else if`', and `puts("At the while.);` just before the `while`, then seeing whether all three of those lines appear consecutively in the output.

Comment: `0 <=` with `<= 1280` and `0 <=` with `<= 1024` are dubious, as displays are not general 1281 pixels by 1025 pixels. Likely `<= 1280` and `<= 1024` ought to be `< 1280` and `< 1024`.

Comment: In any case, you should provide an [mcve].

Comment: There are two `if (...)` It is unclear which one you refer to. Can you be more specific.

Comment: agree @4386427 and I first supposed that concern `if (distance <= 50)` and `if (distance <=250)` grrr

Comment: I refer to the if (distance >250) @4386427

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did the prints and they print depending on how the rocket is launched. When its above certain co-ordinates it only runs the else, however when its below it runs both.

Comment: @MikeyChoong _the if continues to run_ can be interpreted as you are surprised the _if_ after has is test _true_, you are unclear

Comment: @EricPostpischil for the minimal, complete and verifiable, I'm not sure this is possible as I'm using my university's graphics file which isn't accessible to people not at the university.

Comment: BTW what is the interest to have `else if (distance <=250)` rather than `else` after `if (distance >250) {}` ?

Comment: @bruno My program is making a rocket which has to be affected by the gravity of the moon. When the distance from the rocket to the moon is below 250, the rocket's path should be altered by the gravitational force of the moon. However when it's inside the radius of influence, the errors start to occur.

Comment: @MikeyChoong You are misunderstanding what is going on. There is no way you can run both `if (distance >250) { ...}` and `else if (distance <=250) { ... }` in the **same loop**. It is simply impossible. Just put `printf("new loop\n");` as the first thing after `do { `

Comment: @4386427 But when I added the prints inside the distances, both the ones in the if and else print at the same time. Doesn't that mean they're both running at the same time?

Comment: @MikeyChoong if `distance> 250` false then `distance <= 250` is mandatory true, whatever that concern a rocket or something else

Comment: @MikeyChoong It **has** to be different loops! Do this: 1) Add `int loop-count = 0;` before the `do {` 2) Just after `do {` insert `printf("loop_count=%d\n", loop_count++);` You'll soon see that it happens in different loops

Comment: @bruno here is a print screen of both running at the same time. https://imgur.com/a/rT2qm23

Comment: @4386427 I see what you mean, but even if they're not in the same loop, why are they both printing outputs?

Comment: @MikeyChoong You recalculate `distance` in every loop so the next loop may take the other part of the code. Just print `distance` in both code blocks. You already do in the `if` part but not in the `else if`

Comment: @MikeyChoong I understand now, and updated my answer, when at a distance <= 250 your rocket goes too fast and the rocket crosses march

Comment: @bruno yes I see what you mean, I'm gonna try and calculate the new values for x and y and I'll tell you what happens, thanks!

Comment: @MikeyChoong may be the speed/distance is correct but the rocket reaches the surface of march in less than _time_, you have to detect that case

Comment: If the graphics package is used only for output, then a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example could be made by suppressing use of the graphics package. That is, have the program go through all its calculations but send nothing to the graphics program.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> when the else runs and the distance <=250, the if continues to run while the else runs

ok, you mean `distance <=250` then the **next** while turn `distance>250`

This happens when the computed speed/covered distance is too high and the rocket crosses Mars to be on the other side far than 250 (or the rocket enter inside Mars ?) after the delay *time*, that means you have to change

```
    y_pos = initial_y_pos - ((vel_y * time) - ((gravity * time)/2));
    x_pos = initial_x_pos + ((vel_x * time) - ((gravity * time)/2));
    ...
    distance = sqrt(pow((y_pos-(y+312)),2)+(pow((x_pos-(x+440)),2)));
    mars_dist = sqrt(pow((y_pos-150),2)+pow((x_pos-1150),2));
```

to decrease the speed/covered distance in that case if it is too high. Or may be the speed/covered distance is correct but the rocket reaches the surface or Mars in less than *time*, so the new position is incorrect and impossible because that supposes the rocket can cross the surface of Mars, you have to detect that case.